# Why do the characters in Rick and Morty have asterisk-shaped pupils (*)?

Tags: rick-and-morty

I mean like this:

[image: Rick’s face, his eyes are pointing in either direction with the pupil’s looking like asterisks/stars]

As far as I can tell,  all characters, share this trait.

Assuming there's no in-universe explanation,  what's the out-of-universe genesis of the character design?

Another example:

[image: Jerry nervously writes with a pencil, his pupils are asterisk/star shaped]

Comment: Wow, goah, I thought I was seeing Apple Logos on their eyes pupil, but sometimes they also look like grapes.

Comment: https://imgur.com/8sDswGK

Comment: No matter what their explanation is, it's probably just one design attribute used to try to separate the obvious inherited styles from the Simpsons and every clone that came after it. If it were me, I might have drawn them that way to symbolize the chaos of the show and the characters in it

Comment: Side note:   The characters on *Solar Opposites* have the same feature.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The creators discuss the unusual drawing of the pupils in the video below. In short, it's 100% deliberate and is a holdover from the original short film that spawned the series, where the eyes (and the heads) were very sloppily drawn.

When the new animated series was made and the lines were dramatically cleaned up, the artists wanted *something* of the old pilot episode to survive.